# Please guide me to change 1 node standlone to 2 node 1 arbiter Replicate Set

Tags: mongodb

Please guide me to change 1 node standlone (have data) to 2 node 1 arbiter Replicate Set

Answer (score 1):

Please follow [Convert a Standalone to a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/) in the documentation:

> 1. Shut down the [standalone](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-standalone) [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) instance.
> 2. Restart the instance. Use the [--replSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-replset) option to specify the name of the new replica set.For example, the following command starts a standalone instance as a member of a new replica set named rs0. The command uses the standalone’s existing database path of /srv/mongodb/db0:
>
>    > **WARNING**
>    >
>    > Before binding to a non-localhost (e.g. publicly accessible) IP address, ensure you have secured your cluster from unauthorized access. For a complete list of security recommendations, see [Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/). At minimum, consider [enabling authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/#checklist-auth) and [hardening network infrastructure](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-hardening/).
>
>    ```
>    mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /srv/mongodb/db0 --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost,<hostname(s)|ip address(es)>
>    ```
> 3. Connect a [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell to the [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) instance.
> 4. Use [rs.initiate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/#rs.initiate) to initiate the new replica set:
>
>    ```
>    rs.initiate()
>    ```
>
>    The replica set is now operational. To view the replica set configuration, use [rs.conf()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.conf/#rs.conf). To check the status of the replica set, use [rs.status()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.status/#rs.status).